# Using ggplot2 to plot predicted values with robust standard errors

Tags: r, ggplot2, robust

I am trying to use ggplot2 to plot the predicted values of negative binomial regression, one with a binary variable turned on, and another with it turned off. So there will be two two plots that can be compared.

The link [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/nbreg.htm) demonstrates how to do it at the bottom of the page, but I want to be able to create shading around the plot of the predicted values using robust standard errors.  I don't see how to get this from the predict() function.  Is there any work around from this code example to get robust standard errors to shade around the plotted lines?

I use the code here from [this site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/poissonreg.htm) to generate robust standard errors:

```
require(sandwich)
cov.nb1 <- vcovHC(nb1, type = "HC0")
std.err <- sqrt(diag(cov.nb1))
r.est <- cbind(Estimate = coef(nb1), `Robust SE` = std.err, `Pr(>|z|)` = 2 *
    pnorm(abs(coef(nb1)/std.err), lower.tail = FALSE), LL = coef(nb1) - 1.96 *
    std.err, UL = coef(nb1) + 1.96 * std.err)

r.est
```

the model I am using is this:

```
nb1 <- glm.nb(citecount ~ expbin*novcr + expbin*I(novcr^2) + disease + length +
as.factor(year), data = nov4d.dt)
```

And a sample of the data I am using is this:

```
nov4d.dt  <-
    structure(list(PMID = c(1279136L, 1279186L, 1279186L, 1279187L, 
    1279187L, 1279190L, 1279257L, 1279317L, 1279332L, 1279523L), 
        min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), max = c(32L, 
        32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), mean = c(11L, 
        13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 24L, 15L, 8L, 19L), length = c(45L, 
        120L, 120L, 78L, 78L, 136L, 45L, 36L, 171L, 78L), threslength = c(13L, 
        20L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 26L, 4L, 6L, 77L, 14L), novlength = c(5L, 
        6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 36L, 5L), novind = c("TRUE", 
        "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
        "TRUE"), novcr = c(0.111111, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0384615, 0.0384615, 
        0.0441176, 0.0666667, 0.0833333, 0.210526, 0.0641026), novcrt = c(0.288889, 
        0.166667, 0.166667, 0.0897436, 0.0897436, 0.191176, 0.0888889, 
        0.166667, 0.450292, 0.179487), year = c(1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 
        1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1991L, 1992L), disease = structure(c(1L, 
        4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("alz", "bc", 
        "cl", "lc"), class = "factor"), citecount = c(5L, 8L, 8L, 
        12L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 92L, 0L), novind2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), rad = c(FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
        ), exp = c(260, 351, 351, 65, 65, 480, 104, 273, 223, 0), 
        novind4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), novind5 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), novind6 = c(FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
        ), expbin = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), expbin2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), .Names = c("PMID", 
    "min", "max", "mean", "length", "threslength", "novlength", "novind", 
    "novcr", "novcrt", "year", "disease", "citecount", "novind2", 
    "rad", "exp", "novind4", "novind5", "novind6", "expbin", "expbin2"
    ), sorted = "PMID", class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))
```

Answer (score 3):

The link you provide makes a model, creates a synthetic dataset in which one predictor varies along its full range, passes the model and synthetic dataset to predict(), then plots resulting prediction.  The only substantial thing you need to do differently is put your robust std.err into the dataframe to calculate the CI.

```
#look at how model thinks citecount ~ novcr for two values of expbin 
#make synthetic data with a range of range(df$novcr)
#include logical predictor variable expbin
#such that each level of expbin has all the novcr values

newdata2 <- data.frame(novcr = rep(seq(from = min(nov4d.dt$novcr), 
    to = max(nov4d.dt$novcr), length.out = 100), 2), 
    expbin  = rep(0:1, each = 100))

#convert expbin type to logical
newdata2$expbin <- as.logical(newdata2$expbin)

# add in the mean or default values of other predictors
# because I assume predict() needs vals for all parameters in the model
newdata2$length <- mean(nov4d.dt$length,na.rm=T)
newdata2$disease <- factor("alz")
newdata2$year <- factor("1992")
```

(Continue the above until synthetic dataframe has all variables needed by model)

```
#make predict and add it to synthetic data
newdata2$fit <- predict(nb1, newdata2, type = "response")

# include CIs based on your robust se
newdata2$LL <- newdata2$fit - 1.96 * std.err["novcr"]
newdata2$UL <- newdata2$fit + 1.96 * std.err["novcr"]

#plot
ggplot(newdata2, aes(novcr, fit)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL, fill = expbin), 
    alpha = 0.25) + geom_line(aes(colour = expbin), size = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the original question, to provide the model and the sample of the data.  I do have more than 1 predictor.  Given the link on the example (and my own results), I notice that the ribbon range differs, so I don't think that I"ll just be +/- a number to the line.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe that the differing ribbon range is something smart ggplot does to indicate the uncertainty in yvalues where xvalues are absent. It does not mean that a variable se or CI was passed to ggplot.

I'll update my answer to provide more details.

Comment: Let me know if the ribbon on the resulting ggplot does not look as you expect.  The CIs should curve on the edges even though we made them by adding or subtracting a constant from the fit (which the sample code also did).  Add please consider accepting my answer. :-)

Comment: doesn't look right.  the ribbons are wider when I use the nonrobust standard errors.  I would expect these bands to look wider?  I'm wondering if the fact that novcr enters as first and second order terms has something to do with it?

Comment: I would expect wider too.The same thought occurred to me, alternatively we could have some inconsistency in exponentiation and expressing things as rates vs ratios.

One difficulty with working on this is that there isn't enough sample data for the model to run.  I changed a year assignment or two so there'd be enough levels of year for the model, but the model still complains about reaching the iteration limit.  Can you provide a larger subset of data that the model can succeed with?

Comment: Ignoring the plotting question for now, how does std.err (your robust estimate) compare to the std.error you get if you run predict(nb1, newdata2, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE), which I take to be the other std.err you are plotting.

Comment: mb,I have added what I did to answer your questions above.  the se.fit = T standard errors and calculating the standard errors as you describe did not match.  I have a sample of that outcome above.

Comment: The two different standard errors should not match, since that is the point.  The robust estimate is wider than the standard one, which we expect.  The kinda weird thing is that it goes negative, which is not possible for an outcome measure in a negative binomial model.    I still can't actually run the model on your sample data because there isn't enough data, which makes this hard. Can you put enough data and your code in a google doc or paste bin or a gist on github and provide a link?

Comment: link of 1000 obs sample of the data here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eVUscpjLmxzGacL-rUmj6FUq6Ly7PFYkyPuAY0jxzRk/edit